# Car Interior synonym?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a synonym for a car's interior? E.g. 'cockpit', 'cabin', etc.
"He sat quietly in the _____ and waited."

Comment: On a truck, it is the cab. So I think you could use cab or cabin.

Answer (score 1):

The question asked and the example give are at odds and require different answers. The inside of a car is called the “cabin” or the “interior”. (A “cockpit” for a car would only really be appropriate in the context of single-seater or perhaps two-seater, so more a sports car term ex: a roadster.)

In his example, the person could also be in the driver’s seat, so the answer “passenger seat” is not definitive. In the example, words that fit include: car, passenger seat, driver’s seat, and back seat.

Answer (score 0):

In your example sentence, just 'car' works fine. The preposition 'in' already makes clear that the subject is not on the roof or the bonnet.

That said, according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cockpit), a *cockpit* is

> 4 : a space or compartment in a usually small vehicle (such as a boat, airplane, or **automobile**) from which it is steered, piloted, or driven

(emphasis mine) so it's applicable here as well.

If you need to specify the position, consider

> He sat quietly *on* the *driver's/passenger's/rear seat* and waited.

Answer (score 0):

The word that you are looking for is called **passenger seat.**

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passenger%20seat) defines it as

> the front seat of a vehicle (such as a car) where a passenger sits

Also, we can cross verify it with [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/passenger_seat).

> A seat provided in a vehicle for a passenger; specifically (in a motor vehicle) the seat next to the driver

[Word Usage](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/passenger-seat):

"His car was released to his fiancée, who was riding in the **passenger seat** and was sober, Paul said."

"He slouched into the **passenger seat** of the ivory Ford sedan and shut the door hard"